# create partition column from structure streaming json data

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I'm new to structured streaming and would like to a create a partition column based on date column from json message.

Here is the sample message :

```json
{"date": "2022-03-01", "code": "1000310014", "no": "20191362283860", "update_type_cd": "UP", "EventProcessedUtcTime": null, "PartitionId": null, "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": null}

{"date": "2022-03-01", "code": "2000310014", "no": "300191362283860", "update_type_cd": "UP", "EventProcessedUtcTime": null, "PartitionId": null, "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": null}

{"date": "2022-03-01", "code": "30002220014", "no": "20191333383860", "update_type_cd": "UP", "EventProcessedUtcTime": null, "PartitionId": null, "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": null}
```

```py
val date = event.select(col("date"))

val stream = flatten_messages
      .writeStream
      .partitionBy(date)
      .format("delta")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start(output_path)
```

Is this right way partition on json message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in the `partitionBy` you just specify column names, not dataframe. So the code would be just:

```scala
val stream = flatten_messages
      .writeStream
      .partitionBy("date")
      .format("delta")
      .outputMode("append")
      .start(output_path)
```

But the first question would be - do you really need partitioning of the data? It may not be strictly required with Delta that has things like data skipping, ZOrder, etc.

P.S. Also, you may need to cast `date` column to a `date` type - in this case it will be stored more efficiently on the disk, and will allow range search, etc. Although it's not related to partitioning.